# JavaScript || or operator with an undefined variable

Tags: javascript

I have been doing some reading lately one article I read was from Opera.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/

In that article they write this:

> Another common situation in JavaScript
> is providing a preset value for a
> variable if it is not defined, like
> so:

```
if(v){
  var x = v;
} else {
  var x = 10;
}
```

> The shortcut notation for this is the
> double pipe character:

```
var x = v || 10;
```

For some reason, I can't get this to work for me. Is it really possible to check to see if `v` is defined, if not `x = 10`?

--Thanks.
Bryan

Comment: Works great! I do it every day.

Comment: In what sense do you mean it doesn't work for you? Can you elaborate?
Neither of your solution works when v = 0 that's a different fact.

Comment: if your specifically working with integers then you should use `var x = v > 0 ? v : 10`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

That Opera article gives a poor description of what is happening.

While it is true that `x` will get the value of `10` if `v` is `undefined`. It is also true that `x` will be `10` if `v` has *any* "falsey" value.

The "falsey" values in javascript are:

- `0`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- `""` (empty string)
- `false`

So you can see that there are many cases in which `x` will be set to `10` besides just `undefined`.

[Here's some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) detailing the logical operators. (This one is the "logical OR".) It gives several examples of its usage for such an assignment.

Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/V76W6/

```
var v = 0;

var x = v || 10;

alert( x ); // alerts 10
```

Assign `v` any of the falsey values that I indicated above, and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, so you think it would be best to do:
var v = false;
var x = v || 10;
alert(x) ?

Comment: Another way to describe what's effected is: http://jsfiddle.net/robertpitt/V76W6/1/

Comment: @bryan: There's no need to assign `false` to `v`. If you simply do `var v;`, it will automatically have an initial value of `undefined`, so if `v` gets some other non-falsey value, `x` will be assigned that value. But if `v` isn't assigned anything, or gets another falsey value, `x` will get `10`. Keep in mind that `0` is falsey. You should only use the "logical OR" in this manner if you're absolutely certain that you don't want `x` to have *any* falsey value.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Interesting approach. Sort of lays it all out there at once. Nice.

Comment: One more Q, how come when I assign a value to var a on this: http://jsfiddle.net/bryansammon/V76W6/2/ - I still get the alert of 10?

Comment: @bryan: Because you're assigning it *after* `x` has already been assigned. When `x` is assigned, `a` is still `NaN`. You need to move the `a = "5";` line *above* the line that assigns a value to `x`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V76W6/3/)

Comment: Great jsFiddle! I made an objectified version, demonstrating another pitfall: http://jsfiddle.net/V76W6/28/

Answer (score 13):

```
var x = v || 10;
```

That operator (the ["logical" or "short-circuit" OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)) would normally check the value of `v`, and if it is a "falsy" value (*i.e.* it would fail as a condition used in an if statement), `10` becomes the value of `x`, otherwise `v` does (and if `10` were a function, it would never be executed).

`undefined`, `null`, and `0` are all examples of falsy values that a variable can hold (yes, even the first one), and the operator (or if statement) acts accordingly. In contrast, all objects and arrays (not including null) are "truthy" values, which allows for such things as this (used in the Google Analytics tracker code):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || []; // Makes a new array _gaq if it is not already there
```

However, if the referenced variable is **not even declared** anywhere within the scope chain, then a JavaScript exception will occur.

One way to avoid this is by declaring all your global variables from the start:

```
var iAmAGlobalVariable;  // Holds the value undefined by default
```

If this is not possible, you should use the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof). It does not attempt to evaluate its operand, and thus an exception will not occur:

```
var x;
if(typeof v != 'undefined' && v) {
    x = v;
} else {
    x = 10;
}
```

Or even better, if you know that the variable would be a global variable, you can treat it as a property of the global (window) object:

```
var x = window.v || 10;
```

Comment: Well explained answer.

Answer (score 6):

If `v` evaluates to false (for example, `0`, `null`, `false`) then it won't work. You can manually check for undefined:

```
var x = v !== undefined ? v : 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use triple equals with ternary in a function for this.

```
function myTest(x){
 return x === undefined ? true: false;
}
```

Only returns true if x is undefined

See
(http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/)
and
(http://jsfiddle.net/V76W6/)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a try-catch

```
var x = 0;

try
{
    x = v;
}
catch(err)
{
    x = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get it working:

```
var v;         //declare v as undefined
//  v = 5;     //if uncommented x will be 5   

var x = v || 10;
alert(x);      //output: 10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLLtu/1/

Comment: Just for the benefit of the few holdouts who still don't see "javascript" and think "jquery", `$(function() { ... });` is what Eric is referring to as "document ready stuff"; it's jQuery's shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, which is (generally) called when the DOM is finished loading (but before the `load` event on `window`). I'm not sure why it's included in this answer in the first place.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Thanks for the clarification, you're right there's no need for it, I just forgot to delete them, I was first using markup to illustrate the var content instead of the alert.

Comment: I went ahead and removed that portion of your comment. If you would rather I didn't, feel free to rollback.