# Assign only if condition is true in ternary operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Is it possible to do something like this in JavaScript?

```
max = (max < b) ? b;
```

In other words, assign value only if the condition is true. If the condition is false, do nothing (no assignment). Is this possible?

Comment: Is there some reason for avoid using normal `if` statement?

Comment: max  = (max < b) ? b : max ;

Comment: very hacky

    `(max < b)?max = b:0;`

Comment: What's wrong with an `if` statement? It expresses the intention clearly. Or, even better in this example, use [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Don't use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) then, it requires a third argument. You would need to reassign `max` to `max` if you don't want it to change (`max = (max < b) ? b : max`).

An [if-statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) is much more clear:

```
if (max < b) max = b;
```

And if you need it to be an expression, you can (ab)use the short-circuit-evaluation of [AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
(max < b) && (max = b)
```

Btw, if you want to avoid repeating variable names (or expressions?), you could use the [maximum function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
max = Math.max(max, b);
```

Comment: The second one is faster the the first one? Because in terms of memory, seams to be the same amount used.

Comment: How about this:
max < b ? b : null

Is it exactly the same as the single line if, in terms of performance?

Comment: @UtkarshNarainSrivastava well that doesn't assign anything to `max`, and if behaviour is different then performance is irrelevant.

Answer (score 17):

An expression with ternary operator *must* have both values, i.e. for both the true and false cases.

You can however

```
max = (max < b) ? b : max;
```

in this case, if condition is false, value of `max` will not change.

Comment: I'm curious... If the condition is false, under the hood, will it run an operation at all? Or will it replace itself.

Comment: I believe there are always to operations: eval the condition, then assign one of two different values. Of course the eval may result in many operations in itself.

Answer (score 11):

You can just set `max` to itself if the condition is false.

```
max = (max < b) ? b : max;
```

Or you can try using the `&&` operator:

```
(max < b) && (max = b);
```

Or to keep your code simple, just use an `if`.

```
if(max < v) max = b;
```

Answer (score 7):

I think ternary is more suitable 
try this

```
(max < b) ? max = b : '';
```

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a specific operator that isn't the ternary operator, but you can use it like this:

```
max = (max < b) ? b : max;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Performace Results

As most of the answers pretty much tell you almost every possible method, here are some performance results for the four most common methods over 40 million iterations and an average of 10 runs each.

###### Using Ternary

For  `a = b > a ? b : a` the average time was ***90.8ms*** for ***40,000,000*** iterations over 10 runs

Whereas for  `(b > a) && (a = b)` the average time was ***88.7ms*** for ***40,000,000*** iterations over 10 runs

###### Using Math.max

for `a = Math.max(a, b)`  the average time was ***117.3ms*** for ***40,000,000*** iterations over 10 runs

###### Using an if statement

for `if (b > a) a = b`  the average time was ***88.9ms*** for ***40,000,000*** iterations over 10 runs 

***Hope this was interesting!***

Comment: The results depend on a lot of factors (the CPU, the JavaScript interpreter, the version of the JavaScript interpreter etc) but this answer provides a very important conclusion: unless the code does the operation millions of times in a loop, performance-wise it does not matter which option one chooses. Let's choose the one that expresses the intention better. Let the code be clear and easy to read and understand. I would go with `Math.max()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better approach could be

```
max = Math.max(max, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
(max < b) ? max = b : ''
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
(max < b) && (max = b);
```

look at this example:

```js
let max = 10;
let b = 15;
(max < b) && (max = b)// this will be true
console.log("max=", max);

let maxx = 10
let bb = 5;
(maxx < bb) && (maxx = bb)// this will be false
console.log("maxx=", maxx);
```

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation, indeed must be the shorter snippet for the given problem

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is used where we have a minimum of two possible outcomes.

```
let no = 10;
let max = 20;

max = no > max ? no : max
```

if you only want to use if, not else, then I recommend you to use if not the ternary operator.

```
let no = 10;
let max = 20;
    
if (no > max){
   max = no
}
```

if you want to use ternary operator, but don't want to use else part, then you may use this, but this won't be useful in every problem

```
let no = 10;
let max = 20;

no > max ? max = no : 0
```

here we are assigning value to a max variable only when the condition is true, otherwise, we are not doing anything

Comment: The behaviour of `no > max ? max = no : 0` is difficult to understand. It is an expression whose value is not used but has side effects. The reader must make an effort to understand its purpose. Let the code be easy to read and understand. The computer does not care how the code looks like and the differences in performance are not important in 99.9% of the cases.

Comment: Agree, I was just telling the three different ways of doing one thing.

Answer (score 0):

There was no example of ES6, we can use in this way:

```
let list = [{id: "abc", name: "test1"}, {id: "xyz", name: "test2"}]
let selectedData = {};
      list.some((exp) => {
        return (
          exp.id == "xyz" &&
          ((selectedData = exp), true)
        );
      })
console.log(selectedData);
```

---

**Added description after a negative vote:**
Just adding a description to explain my solution. If you have an array of objects and you want if only one condition satisfies then we can use `some`. It will set the `selectedData` when the `id == "xyz"`. As asked in the question, this will assign value only if the condition is true otherwise `selectedData` will be empty.

Comment: This was most likely downvoted as it didn't answer the original question. It was asked if there was a shorthand of an `true ? true : original`. The accepted answer is still the simplest and best answer, even for ES6!

Comment: Maybe it works but what is the human cost for it? The reader must know about and understand the meaning of the comma operator and the meaning of the assignment operator when it is used in an expression. More, they have to juggle with the possible values of `exp.id == "xyz"` struggling to understand when a value is assigned to `selectedData` and when the callback of `Array.some()` returns `true` and why. The code uses `Array.some()` for one of its implementation details (it stops on the first match) and not for its return value. In fact, it is a convoluted implementation of `Array.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the *ternary operator*, you could use [Logical AND assignment (&&=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment).

**Basic examples**

```js
let output = false;
output &&= true;
console.log(output)
```

Reassignment is not possible because `output` has been defined as *false*.

```js
const b = 10;
const max = 1;
let sum = max < b;

sum &&= 'new value';
console.log(sum);
```

Returns a string, because the variable `sum` has been defined as *true*.

Comment: While technically it works, it is a bad idea. The logical operators are meant to be used with logical values (`true` or `false`). JavaScript logical operators are loose, they accept values of any type and their results are of various, sometimes confusing types. Let the code express the intention clearly. In this question the intention is to keep the maximum value (probably of some values that are generated in sequence) in the `max` variable. The logical operators do not help understanding the intention, they divert the attention to unrelated flows and are possible cause of hidden errors.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to assign only if condition to ternary in JavaScript then do following:

`(condition) ? operation : void 0;`

- You have to pass else part otherwise JavaScript interpreter will
  throw error.
- void 0 will return undefined
- It'll be okay to use "null" instead

Answer (score -1):

(A different way) To make the answer more *complicated & useless...*::

```js
      // ;M1;
      let max = 99;
      let b1 = 50;
      let b2 = 100;
      let max_ori = max;
      max = (max < b1) && b1;
      max ||= max_ori;
      expect(max).toEqual(99);
      max = (max < b2) && b2;
      max ||= max_ori;
      expect(max).toEqual(100);
      // ;M2;
      max = 99;
      b1 = 50;
      b2 = 100;
      max = ((max < b1) && b1) || max;
      expect(max).toEqual(99);
      max = ((max < b2) && b2) || max;
      expect(max).toEqual(100);
```

---

> [JavaScript || or operator with an undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-an-undefined-variable)
>
> The **logical OR assignment (`x ||= y`)** operator only assigns if `x` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment
>
> returning immediately with the value of the first [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) operand it encounters; if all values are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the value of the last operand is returned.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND