# Javascript shorthand for assining a value only is variable exists

Tags: javascript

What is a JS shorthand for the following:

```
    if (typeof bfMax !== 'undefined') {
        options.max = bfMax;
    }
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009194/assign-only-if-condition-is-true-in-ternary-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concise, readable, maintainable, shorthand for assigning a value conditionally is:

```
if (typeof bfMax !== 'undefined') {
    options.max = bfMax;
}
```

and it appears that you're already using it.

If you want to minify the script to make it shorter, less readable, and unmaintainable, you can use:

```
typeof bfMax!=='undefined'&&(options.max=bfMax)
```

Of course, you'll want to swap out your variable names to make things shorter:

```
typeof b!=='undefined'&&(o.max=b)
```