# Shorthand for: assign if not false javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, shorthand

looking to see if a shorthand for something I do quite commonly exists.

I commonly write/use functions that will return false if unable to do what they're able to do, but an object if they can.
I also might commonly want to check if was successful.

Eg.

```
function someFunc() {
    // assume a is some object containing objects with or without key b
    // edit: and that a[b] is not going to *want* to be false
    function getAB(a, b) {
        if(a[b]) return a[b];
        return false;
    }

    let ab = getAB(a, b);
    if(!ab) return false;
}
```

I just wanted to know if there was some kind of shorthand for this.
Eg, in fantasy land,

```
//...
let ab = getAB(a, b) || return false
//...
```

Comment: `let ab = getAB(a, b) || false` works just fine

Comment: or just do `return a[b] || false;`

Comment: Not exact but possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009194/assign-only-if-condition-is-true-in-ternary-operator-in-javascript

Comment: In the case of `a = { b: false }`, how is the return result interpreted?

Comment: unsuprisingly, false is falsey so it returns false.
kinda just letting that happen though, i can assume that a does not contain false values, i guess. i'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or operator like:

```
return a[b] || false
```

Your full example code can be written as:

```
function someFunc() {
    // assume a is some object containing objects with or without key b
    function getAB(a, b) {
      return a[b] || false
    }

    return getAB(a, b); // getAB already returns the value, no need to check again.
}
```

Comment: ah, I overlooked.

Comment: Why not `return a[b]` then? seems like the OP wants to exit early actually.