# Best practice for returning "nothing" from a ternary expression if falsy?

Tags: javascript

**Similar question answered here: [Assign only if condition is true in ternary operator in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009194/assign-only-if-condition-is-true-in-ternary-operator-in-javascript)**

This is the ternary condition spec from mdn:

`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

Often I find myself wanting to check if something is true, but I just want to do nothing with the falsy side of the expression. But I'm not sure how to write this:

(someVariable) ? callFunction(someVariable) : *donothing but keep running the script*

Should I use 'false', 'null', '', 'undefined' or something else?

The editor gives me an error if I just leave it open without anything to the right of the `:`

Comment: The ternary operator is designed for returning values, not for flow control. You must return something. It could be an explicit `undefined` if you like, but again, if that return value is irrelevant, ternaries might not be the right tool.

Comment: Ternary operator is not merely `cond ? trueValue : falseValue` but `variable = cond ? trueValue : falseValue`. What value is acceptable to set your variable in the false case? Your question is like asking can we just do `var x =` if we don't want to set `x` to any value? The question itself makes no sense

Comment: That's useful @NicholasTower I hadn't picked up on that nuance. @slebetman The question in my opinion makes sense if your goal is to check for a null value and do stuff only if the value is truthy. It's not equivalent to your example `var x =` because I clearly do add the exprIfTrue by calling a function (callFunction(someVariable)). The condition is a variable which is truthy or falsy and my example is thus valid as long as I (as Mr. Tower points out) do return something from the falsy side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `(someCondition) && doifTrue`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND (Short Circuit Evaluation)

Comment: Very useful, when searching for your expression I found another answer to the same question, that is well answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009194/assign-only-if-condition-is-true-in-ternary-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

might come handy (condition) && (if true -> do this)

Answer (score 0):

Not a ternary.
It's a function that the params is ...spreadArr.

```
let getFuncVal = (...data) => {
  return data.filter(Boolean);
};

console.log(getFuncVal('', 1, 2, 0))
```

Comment: Interesting angle here, but my question regards variables/conditions representing any kind of truthy/falsy value, not only booleans (this may not have been entirely clear, though).