# "||" operator is not working when assigning value to a variable

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code?

```
var sha = 6;
var secondParameter = dan || sha;
alert(secondParameter);
```

I tried it with many browsers. No alert. 
If I add var dan like this:

```
var sha = 6;
var dan = 5;
var secondParameter = dan || sha;
alert(secondParameter);
```

the alert will happen. So the problem in "||". I saw many codes where it use the operator like this! So I have no idea..

Comment: `dan` is not defined. look at the error console.

Comment: Trying to access an undefined variable causes an error.

Comment: There is a big difference between an undefined variable and a variable with an undefined value.

Comment: As far as I know the only purpose to use "||" in this way is to assign "sha" to "secondParameter" when "dan" is not defined. And by the way when dan is (defined) false value the problem is the same.

Comment: If var dan; (a variable with an undefined value) the problem still exist.So what you said is NOT the problem.

Comment: @dannyalkhald: No, the problem does *not* still exist. http://jsfiddle.net/NhsgN/

Comment: My mistake was dan; or dan = null; (Not using the var keyword).

Answer (score 7):

You don't have the `dan` defined. Execution stops at that error. Check the browser console for errors.

When you define `dan`, execution continues, but that's probably not what you want.

The purpose of such code in JavaScript is to say if `dan` has a falsy value (any value that evaluates to a `false` value, i.e. `0`, `''`, `null`, `false`, `undefined`, or `NaN`), then use the value of `sha`.

IF defining `dan` is beyond your responsibility, (i.e some other script should have set it), then you can check for its existence using a construct like follows:

`secondParameter = typeof(dan) == 'undefined' ? sha : dan;`

(Not tested, hopefully it works. :) anyways, it should give you an idea)

[Check here for documentation on logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Also, this question might give you more insight: [Javascript || or operator with a undefinded variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-a-undefinded-variable)

Comment: Actually I was trying to use the "||" instead of the ternary operator. Now I know when to use each of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var sha = 6;
var dan = null;
var secondParameter = dan || sha;
alert(secondParameter);
```

Try this. You can coalesce using the `||` operator, but all variables have to be declared in order to be referenced

Comment: Btw you dont need to set it to null just `var dan;` would suffice.

Comment: I tried the tow versions before I ask. Both of them don't work.

Comment: Ok now I see. the problem was that I didn't use "var" keyword.

Comment: @dannyalkhald you should really provide more context here. Be careful when you add "var" as it redefines the dan for current scope, and hides any existing dan, point is: just adding a keyword may not be the proper solution, try to learn how variables/scope behaves in JavaScript

Comment: I know that var define the scope of the variable but I don't know why it's significant in this context.

Comment: The absence of _var_ means that a variable will be treated as global.

Answer (score 1):

This is used in a situation where it is given as something like a parameter but isn't assigned a value or it is `falsy`

`falsy` being `0, false, null or undefined`

For example:

```
var sha = 6;
var dan = undefined;
var secondParameter = dan || sha;
alert(secondParameter);
```

You will get `6`

A good example to use this would be something like this:

```
function funcWithCallback(callback){
     callback = callback || function(){};
     callback();
}
```

In this example if callback is undefined (or `falsy`) then set callback as a new instance of a function

Using it in a situation like this will ensure no error

Comment: Javascript exacerabates this confusion by allowing you to explicitly assign `undefined` to a variable, and it's different from not defining the variable in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: I was more so explaining the situation where you could use it. 

The problem with the code is that `dan` is not defined at all which is the answer, but thats to easy..

Comment: If I use an object as the function argument like this function: function da (d){this.a = d.a || 5;} will it work?

Comment: if d is an object then yes given d.a is falsy 5 would be taken. Eg if you call da like so `da({})` then `this.a` will equal `5` however is you call `da();` then you will get a javascript error `can not call property 'a' of undefined` or something similar

Comment: @dannyalkhald In your example I would check if d was passed and has an a property: `this.a=(d===undefined)?5:(d.a===undefined)?5:d.a;`

Comment: @SmartLemon Great! That's exactly the situation that I want to use the "||" operator  for.

Comment: @ HMR I will check for the d object, but is it necessary to check if it has the a property?

Comment: @ HMR This says It's not necessary to check for the property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288317/undefined-vs-defined-window-property-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in how JavaScript handles undeclared variables (undefined variable) and undefined values. In the following example the variable `dan` is declared but never set so it's value is `undefined` the || returns the first `true` value it can find so if I pass anything but an empty string, 0, false, NaN, undefined or NULL it'll console.log the passed value. Else it'll log "default value".

```
function test(dan){
  console.log(dan || "default value");
  return dan===undefined;
}
console.log(test());//default value, then true
console.log(test(22));//22 then false
```

A more robust way of checking if a variable was passed would be to see if the variable's value is undefined:

```
function test(dan){
  dan = (typeof(dan)==='undefined')?"default value":dan;
}
```

In your example the variable `dan` is not declared at all (variable is undefined), that's why you get error "dan is not defined" because dan is not declared at all.

```
function test(){
  return dan===undefined;//ReferenceError: dan is not defined
}
console.log(test());
```

You could change your code to this:

```
var sha = 6, dan;//dan is declared here but no value is set
var secondParameter = dan || sha;
console.log(dan===undefined);//true
console.log(secondParameter);//6
```

If you want to check if a certain object has a property then it'll not throw an error:

```
function test(){
  return window.neverSetOrDeclared===undefined;
}
console.log(test());//true
```

It will throw an error when you try to check a property of undefined or null:

```
null.something//throws error
undefined.something//throws error
window.neverSetOrDeclared===undefined//throws error
```

Comment: Its not safe to compare a variable directly to 'undefined' as in some cases, undefined itself can be assigned to something else, in which case these checks will fail. Better way is to check with typeof operator: typeof(dan) === 'undefined'

Comment: @BuddhiP You are correct but who in their right mind would re define undefined or window? A way around it is to do like jQuery: (function(window,undefined){your code })(window); If you're making a library to be consumed by anyone (even those who re define window and or udefined) than you make a valid point.

Comment: typeof(dan) will not throw an error when dan wasn't declared (undefined variable). So the example code won't behave the same.

Comment: it will not throw errors when `dan` is undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/Gv52L/1/, And yes no one in 'right mind' will do it, but right mind is a relative term :). 
Some programmers write same as (undefined == varname) (practice from other languages where writing if (null == var) to prevent accidental assignments), but in those cases they may cause accidental assignments in JS (undefined = varname) bcs JS doesn't prevent assigning to 'undefined'.. that's one way this could break. Anyways, my point is its better to be safe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: the way this || works is : if first condition is false then it checks second condition. So in order to display second parameter, you'll have to make first parameter null.