# Undefined vs. defined window property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the following two statements (in the context of the global window)?

```
(function() { return a; } )(); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
(function(a) { return a; } )(); // returns undefined
```

I assume it has something to do with the following:

```
  a; // ReferenceError: a is not defined
  window.a; // undefined
```

It seems the second function goes up the scope chain and ends at the global window scope, where `a` is not a property of window and thus returns `undefined`. But shouldn't the first function also do the same and return `undefined` as well?

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833661/what-is-the-difference-in-javascript-between-undefined-and-not-defined) about undefined vs. not defined, but it seems to apply more relating to variables and not about properties in the window scope.

Comment: For the second function it accepts a parameter but you passed nothing to it, so it is `undefined`. It is *not* a property of `window`, but a local variable.

Comment: Thanks Alvin! I totally forgot about testing for passing back a parameter to the function, seem to often misuse self-invoking functions

Comment: @hermantran: they are not self-invoking, but immediately executed. Self-invocation is when a function calls itself from its body. `function foo() { foo(); }` <--- here is a self-invocation

Comment: undefined variable and undefined value is not the same in JavaScript. You can check on an object if it has a property defined like `window.neverDeclaredOrSet===undefined` but you can't check a variable in the same way. You can check variables like this `typeof(someVar)==="undefined"`, that won't throw an error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287905/operator-is-not-working-when-assigning-value-to-a-variable/17288118#17288118

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the distinction, I definitely was under the impression that self-invoking and IIFE meant the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that this is a common pitfall and an important question, if you're reading this and *anything* is unclear please let me know in the comments.

## In short

- `a;` - will throw a reference error because it's trying to access an undefined variable
- `function() { return a; } )();` - this is exactly like the case above, it's an access to an undefined variable
- `object.a` - will return undefined, we're not trying to access an undefined variable here, but rather the property of a known object, this is different
- `(function(a) { return a; } )();` - will return undefined, `a` is a parameter here and not an undefined variable, it will be assigned the actual language primitive value type `undefined`.

Let's dig a little bit deeper shall we?

## The spec

---

Let's see what the language specification has to say about all these cases:

### Undeclared variable reference

The spec states [here:](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)

> If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a **ReferenceError** exception.

The spec states:

> IsUnresolvableReference(V). Returns **true** if the base value is **undefined** and **false** otherwise.

This is why the following happens:

```
a; // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Since the base value is not defined, it throws a reference error as the spec specifies.

### Undeclared object property

In an object, base is not undefined (it's the object) so it's all good and no error is thrown. It is resolved as such:

> The following [[Get]] internal method is used by GetValue when V is a property reference with a primitive base value. It is called using base as its this value and with property P as its argument. The following steps are taken:
>
> Let O be ToObject(base).
>
> Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of O with property name P.
>
> If desc is undefined, return **undefined**.

Which, is why you see:

```
window.a; // undefined
```

### Function parameter

The other case - parameter is completely different, the parameter exists, but its value is set to the primitive value type undefined. There is a difference between existing and being undefined and not existing :)

This is [specified here](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5):

> If n is greater than argCount, let v be undefined otherwise let v be the value of the n’th element of args.

Which is why:

```
(function(a) { return a; } )(); // returns undefined
```

Comment: Thank you Benjamin for the detailed post and spec reference! Very enlightening stuff

Comment: @hermantran I'm glad I could help, let me know if there is anything you don't understand here :) The [language specification](http://es5.github.io/) is pretty well written and there are constant attempts to make it even more readable, it's a good resource to check when in doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

You're really over-thinking your second case: `(function(a) { return a; } )(); // returns undefined`

Yes, but it has nothing to do with this:

> ... goes up the scope chain and ends at the global window scope, where a is not a property of window and thus returns undefined

You defined a parameter for the function, named `a`. Because you didn't supply a value, it is `undefined`. It's really that simple.