# jquery script works only on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After 2 weeks of hard work on my first, simple site/database I'm stuck. Friend of mine helped me on adding jquery, but now it works only in Mozilla, and he dont have idea why. I dont know java at all (and barely php). Can you take a look?

Chrome console point an error at

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

at line 49 which is

```
self.dataAdapter = function(id = 0, imie = '', nazwisko = '', kredyt = 0)
```

Do you have any idea what is the most compatible syntax?

The whole script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    sui = new swiezakUI();
    sui.getData();
});

function swiezakUI() 
{
    var self = this;
    self.scriptURL = "/data.php";

    self.send = function(key, stuff)
    {
        var post = {};
        post[key] = JSON.stringify(stuff);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: self.scriptURL,
            data: post,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                self.getData();
                self.cleanForm();
            },
            failure: function(errMsg)
            {
                alert('fail');
            },
            error: function(errMsg)
            {
                alert("Blad \n" + errMsg.responseText);
            }
        });     
    }

    self.id2Id = function(id)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < self.myData.length; i++)
        {
            if(id == self.myData[i].id) 
                return i;
        }
    }

    self.dataAdapter = function(id = 0, imie = '', nazwisko = '', kredyt = 0)
    {
        var data = new Object();
        data.id = id;
        data.imie = imie;
        data.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        data.kredyt = kredyt;
        return data;
    }

    self.dodajNowy = function()
    {
        return function()
        {
            var data = self.dataAdapter(null, $('#imie').val(), $('#nazwisko').val(), $('#kredyt').val().replace(/\D+/g,""));
            self.send('nowy',data);
        }
    }

    self.edytujWpis = function(id)
    {
        return function()
        {
            var data = self.dataAdapter(id, $('#imie').val(), $('#nazwisko').val(), $('#kredyt').val().replace(/\D+/g,""));
            self.send('edycja',data);
        }
    }

    self.kasujWpis = function(id)
    {
        return function()
        {
            var data = self.dataAdapter(id);
            self.send('kasuj',data);
        }
    }

    self.cleanForm = function()
    {
        $('#imie').val('');
        $('#nazwisko').val('');
        $('#kredyt').val('');
        $('#bZapisz').unbind();
        $('#bZapisz').click(self.dodajNowy());
    }

    self.editButtons = function()
    {
        $('.edit').click(function()
        {   
            var did = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D+/g,"");
            id = self.id2Id(did);
            $('#imie').val(self.myData[id].imie);
            $('#nazwisko').val(self.myData[id].nazwisko);
            $('#kredyt').val(self.myData[id].kredyt);
            $('#bZapisz').unbind();
            $('#bZapisz').click(self.edytujWpis(did));          
        });
    }

    self.delButtons = function()
    {
        $('.delete').click(function()
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D+/g,"");
            console.log(id);
            self.kasujWpis(id)();
        });
    }

    $('#bZapisz').click(self.dodajNowy());

    $('#bCzysc').click(function(){
        self.cleanForm();
    });

    self.getData = function()
    {
        $('#lista').children('table').html("<tr><th>id</th><th>imie</th><th>nazwisko</th><th>kredyt</th>"+ 
            "<th>edycja</th><th>usun</th></tr>");
        $.getJSON(self.scriptURL, function(data)
        {           
            console.log(data);
            self.myData = data;

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                $('#lista').children('table').append(
                    '<tr><td>'+ data[i].id +'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+ data[i].imie +'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+ data[i].nazwisko +'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+ data[i].kredyt +'</td>'+
                    '<td><button class="edit" id="e#'+data[i].id+'">e</button></td>'+
                    '<td><button class="delete" id="d#'+data[i].id+'">d</button></td></tr>');
            }

            self.editButtons();
            self.delButtons();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax, JavaScript doesn't have default arguments (yet). It might work in FF because they have implemented some future ES6 features, but you shouldn't use it in production.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
What do you suggest? Should i check for correct syntax in documentation, and try to fix it somehow, or maybe should I leave this method/library and try something easier?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters) are currently part of the [ES6 draft](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts). This feature is not part of the most recent final ECMAScript standard (5.1), hence [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters#Browser_Compatibility) is currently minimal. As of this writing, only Firefox (experimentally) implements default parameters.

There are many ways to simulate default parameters. An alternative to ES6's default parameters would be comparing `arg === undefined` to set the default value for it:

```
//if the kredyt argument has not been passed or is undefined
if (kredyt === undefined) {
   kredyt = 0;
}
```

When a function is called passing less arguments than its parameters count, the parameters without corresponding arguments are initialized to `undefined`.

This way, not passing a value for the argument as well as explicitly passing `undefined` as the argument value will use the default parameter value, the same behavior as ES6's default parameters.

So here's the complete example:

```
self.dataAdapter = function(id, imie, nazwisko, kredyt)
{
    //default parameters
    if (id === undefined) {
        id = 0;
    }
    if (imie === undefined) {
        imie = '';
    }
    if (nazwisko === undefined) {
        nazwisko = '';
    }
    if (kredyt === undefined) {
        kredyt = 0;
    }

    //function code
    var data = new Object();
    data.id = id;
    data.imie = imie;
    data.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    data.kredyt = kredyt;
    return data;
}
```

---

Another common approach is comparing `arg == null`, which has the same effect but also accepts passing `null` to use the default parameter value:

```
//if kredyt is null, undefined or not passed
if (kredyt == null) {
   kredyt = 0;
}
```

This works because `==` does type coercion, and `null` coerces to, and only to, `undefined` ([ES5#11.9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)).

---

Yet another common approach is to use the `||` as the "default operator" (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576867/1331430)):

```
kredyt = kredyt || 0; //in the beginning of the function
//...
data.kredyt = kredyt;
```

Or if the parameter is used only in a single place, it is possible to inline it as well:

```
data.kredyt = kredyt || 0;
```

The benefit is basically shorter code, but note that it will use the default parameter value not only when the argument is `undefined`, but also `null`, `false`, `0`, empty string or `NaN`. Hence this is not a viable approach when one of these values is an acceptable parameter value different from its default parameter value.

---

Lastly, for use cases that need to differentiate a `null`/`undefined` value from a not passed argument (which is rare and not the case here), it's possible to check the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object's [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/length) property:

```
if (arguments.length < 4) {
    kredyt = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got the idea. I've even tried to put it into jss file here and there (plus the same way to simulate others parameters), but I havent worked yet. Where should I put it?

Comment: in the first lines of the function definition. I've added a full example to the answer.

Comment: It works just fine. Without your help I wouldnt handle it. Thank you VERY much.