# What it means if variable value contains OR (||) operator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn some javascript by working my way through some existing code and I came across this variable definition which I have not seen in the past. After searching I could not find an explanation so figured I would post here.

```
var colorCollection = colorCollection || {};
```

Could someone shed some light on what this type of definition means and why one might use this.

Comment: perhaps this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-a-undefinded-variable

Comment: If `colorCollection` is falsy, `colorCollection` will default to `{}`. It's commonly used as a hack for optional function parameters in JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) or [In Javascript, what does it mean when there is a logical operator in a variable declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088098/in-javascript-what-does-it-mean-when-there-is-a-logical-operator-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assigning `colorCollection` to its own value if it already exists, otherwise it will assign it an empty object.

It works like this - in javascript, any variable is "truthy", meaning that you can say something like this:

```
if (colorCollection) {
 // some code 
}
```

If `colorCollection` has a value (ie. it isn't `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `""`, or `false`), the if statement will be true, and the code in `// some code` will run. The `||` operator will return the first value if it's truthy, otherwise it will return the last value. That's why this works.