# Combining 2 jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery is starting to get unnecessarily long. Is there a way to easily combine these 2 functions. My first thought is to create a custom event out of the key down function. Any solutions or suggestions on what to read up on would be appreciated.

```
$('th:nth-child(3):first').click(function () {
    $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
});

$('th:nth-child(3):first').keydown(function(event){    
    if(event.keyCode==13){
       $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('th:nth-child(3):first').on('change keydown', function(event) {    
    if(!event.keyCode || event.keyCode==13){
       $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
    }
});
```

This will fire on both `change` and `keydown` events, and will only call `change()` if `event.keyCode` does not exist (`change`) or is equal to `13` (`keydown`).

Comment: It works I just needed to change the "change" to "click". Thank you.

Comment: JamesDonnelly - If you have time could you possibly explain what is going on in this line of code so I know for the future " if(!event.keyCode || event.keyCode==13){ ". specifically what do the "!" and "||" do. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: The "!" means not (true => false and vice-versa) and the "||" means OR. See a small explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-a-undefinded-variable

Answer (score 2):

```
function combined(event) {
    if (typeof event === 'undefined' || event.keyCode==13)
        $('#dtSelect').val(2).change();
}

$('th:nth-child(3):first').click(combined).keydown(combined);
```

although in this case I don't think it's worth combining them.