# javascript if Null check

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I found this code in JavaScript tutorial. It reads if value is null the this.current is assigned to 0, otherwise to a value. How does it work?
I am confused because there is no `null` or ?? operator in the code.

`this.current=value||0;`

Comment: Something to note is that null is falsy.

Comment: The best explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802055/what-does-the-construct-x-x-y-mean

Comment: Or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4576915/3791314 because it explains truthy/falsy values

Comment: JavaScript's OR operator doesn't return boolean true/false values like other languages. Rather it checks if the left evaluates to true when type casted to boolean, If true, it returns the value rather than a boolean. If false, then it returns the second value regardless of its value. Thus in JavaScript, the following two statements are equivalent: `$result=$value1||$value2;` `$result=$value1?$value1:$value2;` the weakness with the `?:` syntax is we need to dedicate a statement for assigning the value which isn't possible in the midst of another statement, thus `||` can be very powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the semantics of the `||` (logical or) operator is such that as soon as its left side is *truthy*, it short-circuits and returns that value, otherwise it returns what's on the right side.

That common pattern takes advantage of the semantics by passing a possibly *falsy* (x) value and a *default* (y) to the operator: `x || y`. If x turns out to be non-falsy, that whole expression evaluates to `x`, otherwise `y`.

`Null` is not mentioned there, because `null` is *falsy* and the pattern works for all falsy values.

Answer (score 1):

This is how operator `||` in javascript work. Instead of returning a boolean value, it returns either operand depending on whether they are true or not.

If the first operand is a "true" value, it returns its value directly without even looking at the other operand, else it just returns the other operand's value.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, On the right side you have `value || 0` That evaluates to the `this.current`. What you need to understand is the right side evaluates the boolean `OR` first. That is how JS `||` supposed to work. It return the value instead of `TRUE/FALSE` if they are not boolean.

Answer (score -5):

If you compare something using === it will compare the value and type. For example

```
var a = false;
If(a == null){
   //triggered
}

If(a === null){
 //not works
 }
```

Comment: That was not the OP's question.