# What's the purpose of the || [] operator

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at this Javascript class:

```
'use strict';
class Account {
  constructor(a, b, c) {
    this.a = a
    this.b = b || []
    this.c = c || []
  }
}
```

What is `b || []` saying?

Comment: if be b can be evaluated to false it will return [], otherwise it returns b

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-a-undefinded-variable

Comment: you can use it as a default initializer if the left side var is (falsy) wich means, that holds a 0, false, undefined... the value from the right side of the || will be used, in this case, an empty array will be assigned to the var

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator returns the first truth-y value that it sees. Many people will use this as a shortcut to set default values for variables as `undefined` is false-y. The issue in doing so is that the default will also be used for `null`, `false`, `0`, `NaN`, and empty strings (all of which may or may not actually be valid values).

In this case, if `b` or `c` is `undefined` (or any other false-y value), `this.b` and `this.c` will be set to `[]`.

Comment: what about `null` and `""` -.-

Comment: @CodeiSir - I added `null` and already mentioned empty strings.