# Is there something like Nothing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is not a problem, just personal curiosity.

I've found a weird edge-case and I don't know if my brain is messing up or if JavaScript simply lacks this. From an SQL-Query that returns columns of Strings that can also be null, I want to put them into an array. However, I want those arrays to be empty when the strings are null.

If I do the following, the arrays will contain *null* as entry instead of staying empty:

```
// Column A and B can be either a String or null
var sqlColumnA = sqlResults[i][1];
var sqlColumnB = sqlResults[i][2];

// Store them within arrays of an objects ONLY IF they are a String
var obj = {
    a : [sqLColumnA],
    b : [sqlColumnB]
};
```

To bypass this, I'd have to use a ternary operator like this:

```
sqlColumnA === null ? [sqlColumnA] : []
```

Obviously it works, but it got me thinking. Is there something like *Nothing* in JavaScript? Where a variable isn't just null, but literally empty? Or will I not be able to bypass the ternary operator solution?

Comment: check out undefined

Comment: you're going to end up with a single element array which has the value `undefined`, or `null` - there is no way to avoid the ternary (or some variation thereof)

Comment: _“Where a variable isn't just null, but literally empty?”_ - null is the explicit, intentional absence of any value. What “literally empty” would be supposed to mean, you would have to define first.

Comment: do you get the value `null` or a string with the value `'null'`?

Comment: No, JS doesn't have a `Maybe` data type like in Haskell which can take only two values like `Just data` or `Nothing`. So what you do is what you can do as far as JS can get.

Comment: @CBroe My definition of "literally empty" would be that such a variable would return absolutely nothing and thus produce an array of length 0 when put into one: `[literallyEmptyVariable] == []`

Answer (score 1):

If you want an actually *empty* (as in zero length) array you will need the ternary operator (or similar syntax) as per your question. There is no way to avoid it.

---

In actual fact javascript has at least 2 way to define "not there" - [Both `null` and `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript).

Comment: You don't need the ternary operator. You could use the shortcut with `||` as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576915/457268

Comment: @k0pernikus the problem with that example is it wont work here as `[null]` is truthy (has a length of 1) so the ternary is the shorter syntax in this rare case

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be to use `.filter(Boolean)` on the array to get rid of all falsey values (`null`, `undefined`, `''`, `NaN`, `0` and blanks)

```js
var arr = [null, 1, 2, 3, '', undefined, 'a', NaN,,, 0, 'b', {}];

console.log(arr.filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: it looks that an empty string is a valid result.

Comment: Sidenote: `[]` and `{}` are truthy values as far as JS is concerned.

Comment: @k0pernikus I know, that's why I included it. It gets returned in the output when you execute the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

[`void 0` example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291942/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean)

Comment: From the linked question's answer: `The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined primitive value, usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void 0”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a 'nothing' and it's called `undefined`.

```
var empty;
console.log(empty);
```

Output: `undefined`.

https://jsfiddle.net/96h7vn2z/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use values, which are not `null` or not `'null'` as string.

```js
console.log([null, 'null', '', 'value'].map(v => v !== null && v !== 'null' ? [v] : []));
```