# JavaScript namespace object literal

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I've recently come across JavaScript Namespaces and how you can use them to create namespaces like other popular OOP languages. I have confusion on how they are declared. For example,

`var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};`

creates a namespace called `myNamespace` if it hasn't already been created. If it was created, just pass it into `var myNamespace`.

I have trouble understanding what `myNamespace || {}` actually does.

Wouldn't `myNamespace` be undefined at first? How would you compare that in a Boolean expression.

Also, how does the object literal `{}` work? Does it create an empty object and assign that to `myNamespace` to work as a namespace?

I've tried looking for the answer on SO, but there's too much saturation about the practices on how to declare different types of namespaces.

Comment: undefined || {} === {}. And yes, {} is just an empty object

Comment: `||` is "or". "if `myNamespace` is already defined, assign it to `myNamespace`, otherwise, assign `myNamespace` an empty object."

Comment: This approach to namespacing is obsoleted by ES6 modules.

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576867/javascript-or-operator-with-a-undefinded-variable

Comment: @torazaburo What is the best approach to creating namespacing in ES6 then?

Comment: @JustinJmnz Sounds like a good question, however is irrelevant to this one.

Comment: @JustinJmnz For all practical purposes, an ES6 module (file) can be considered a namespace. It behaves almost precisely like a namespace if it is imported as `import * as myNamespace from 'foobar';`.

Comment: @JustinJmnz Did any of the answers help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `||` was originally intended to work with booleans, it is implemented in a very handy way that allows it to work to set default values:

```
function or(a, b) {
  if (a) return a
  else return b
}
```

You can test this in your head and see that it works with booleans: if `a` is `true`, the result is `true` so the result is the same as `a`. If `a` is `false` then the result depends on `b`.

Variable declarations with `var` in JavaScript work a bit strangely. You are allowed to redeclare a variable with the same identifier in the same scope. So the way the code works is:

- If `myNamespace` is already declared, you redeclare the variable without assigning to it yet. You get the value from the old declaration of `myNamespace`. This value is assumed to be truthy, so the `||` will return it.
- If `myNamespace` is not yet declared, you declare it and then `myNamespace` will be `undefined`, a falsy value. So the `||` will return the second value, the `{}`, and that is the value that will get assigned to `myNamespace`.

It may make sense to read it in two separate steps:

```
//Declare the variable if it doesn't exist,
//without overwriting an existing value
var myNamespace
//Take the value of myNamespace (undefined if it didn't exist yet)
//and replace it with {} if it is falsy
myNamespace = myNamespace || {}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};`

Does exactly what you said it does.

`||` is an `or` operator as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

So what this is doing is, saying `var myNamespace = myNamespace` however, if `myNamespace` is undefined, then it will just go to the right hand side of the operator and just create an empty object like this (you were right about this):

`var myNamespace = {}`

Let me know if I seem confused, I think I addressed your points.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the definition of `||` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> expr1 || expr2
>
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2.

Now try

```
console.log(undefined == true);
```

This will print `false`, which means that `undefined` cannot be converted to `true` (we are using the `==` operator to let JavaScript use type coercion). As a result, if `myNamespace` is undefined, an empty object literal will by assigned to it (which is equivalent to `expr2` from the quote).